# Appending Multiple Items To Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML div element with an id of `controls`.

I am trying to append a `div` with a 2 `input` fields via:

```
this.controls = controlBtns
    .append('div')
    .classed({'time-container': true})
    .append('input')
    .attr({type: 'number', min: '0', max: '24', step:'1', value:'00', 'disabled': 'disabled'});
```

Which results in:

```
<div id="controls">
    <div class="time-container">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="24" steps="1" value="01:00">
    </div>
</div>
```

However, i want to end up with 2 `input` field so:

```
<div id="controls">
    <div class="time-container">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="24" steps="1" value="01:00">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="60" steps="1" value="01:00">
    </div>
</div>
```

The above `inputs` represent hours (24) and minutes (60). However, when i try:

```
this.controls = controlBtns
    .append('div')
    .classed({'time-container': true})
    .append('input')
    .attr({type: 'number', min: '0', max: '24', step:'1', value:'00', 'disabled': 'disabled'})
    .append('input')
    .attr({type: 'number', min: '0', max: '60', step:'1', value:'00', 'disabled': 'disabled'});
```

The result is:

```
<div id="controls">
    <div class="time-container">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="24" steps="1" value="01:00">
    </div>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="60" steps="1" value="01:00">
</div>
```

How can i result in:

```
<div id="controls">
    <div class="time-container">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="24" steps="1" value="01:00">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="60" steps="1" value="01:00">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is tagged jQuery. Are using jQuery as well?

Comment: Yes i am using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var timeContainer = controlBtns
  .append('div')
  .classed({'time-container': true});
timeContainer
  .append('input')
  .attr({type: 'number', min: '0', max: '24', step:'1', value:'00', 'disabled': 'disabled'});
timeContainer
  .append('input')
  .attr({type: 'number', min: '0', max: '60', step:'1', value:'00', 'disabled': 'disabled'});

this.controls = timeContainer;
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, you can append entire HTML snippet. So, you can do this

```
$('#controls").append('<div class="time-container"><input type="number" min="0" max="24" steps="1" value="01:00"><input type="number" min="0" max="60" steps="1" value="01:00"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
$("#controls").append('<div class="time-container"></div>');
var timeContainer = $("#controls").find('.time-container');
timeContainer
    .append('<input />')
    .find('input')
    .last()
    .attr({type: 'number', min: '0', max: '24', step:'1', value:'00', 'disabled': 'disabled'});
timeContainer
    .append('<input />')
    .find('input')
    .last()
    .attr({type: 'number', min: '0', max: '60', step:'1', value:'00', 'disabled': 'disabled'});
```

This should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the input is number I'm not sure I could use value with a format like "01:00" only "1" and for the append part I prefer to use "appendTo" so I could set where to append the input. I see there is an append of second DIV, I think the rest of the append part should be inside this II div.

```js
controlBtns = $('#controls');

$('<div>').attr({
'id': 'numbersWrapper'
}).appendTo( controlBtns );

$('<input>').attr({
'type':'number',
'min':'0',
'max':'24',
'steps':'1',
'value':'1',
'id': 'hrs'
}).appendTo('#numbersWrapper' );

$('<input>').attr({
'type':'number',
'min':'0',
'max':'60',
'steps':'1',
'value':'1',
'id': 'mins'
}).appendTo( '#numbersWrapper' );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="controls"></div>
```